# How to add components to JDialog

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, jdialog

```
   d1=new JDialog();
   d1.setSize(200, 100);
   t1=new JTextField();
   t1.setBounds(10,10,40,20);
   d1.add(t1);
```

I want to add components in JDialog such as TextField, Button...

Comment: Use suggestions of component sizing in constructors and layouts.  `null` layouts will not work in the real world.

Comment: Show ASCII art or drawing of how it should look when it appears.  If resizable, shows a second with extra width and height.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) first create a Jpanel

```
JPanel pan=new JPanel();
pan.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

2) add the components to that JPanel

```
pan.add(new JLabel("label"));
pan.add(new JButton("button"));
```

3) create JDialog

```
JDialog jd=new JDialog();
```

4) add the JPanel to JDialog

```
jd.add(pan);
```

Comment: can't i take the any layout for Jpanel

Comment: Why don't you try it with your code (and a `BorderLayout`) and see that happens?

Comment: Which exact part of **`BorderLayout`** are you having trouble understanding?  What happens when you use `BorderLayout`?  Add a screenshot.

Comment: ya,it's working with BorderLayout,But the bottom part was not appearing

Comment: *"But the bottom part was not appearing"*  Odd definition of 'working'.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson i just edited my post to "except border layout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13221/discussion-between-ramravi8-and-andrew-thompson)

Comment: see this output here [postimage.org/image/utjbb7x5v]

Comment: `//except BorderLayout
` ..Or `CardLayout` or.. change that to `// an appropriate layout` and it becomes a correct statement.

Comment: i'm not adding the these layout to JDialog ,i'm adding to the panel,then i'm adding that panel to JDialog..it working..

Comment: Show me an SSCCE and a screenshot using a `CardLayout`.

Comment: i taken time to do this ..cardLayout screens [http://postimage.org/image/z7jmfcrvn/] and [http://postimage.org/image/g6fa/6comp] you want me to show my code?

Comment: Both 404.  I will invest no further time in this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you use no layout manager.

```
d1.setLayout(null);
```

By default, a BorderLayout is used. It is great to use layout manager, but the real good ones, that make your windows resizable etc, are hard to understand. Without layout manager, you can specify the bounds as you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can add components to a JDialog just the way you add to a JFrame since JDialog is a java.awt.Container . You should use a a layout manager or set the layout to null if you want to set the sizes of the components you are adding.

Comment: __The only difference is that a JDialog will be need to be added to a parent container (like a JFrame)__ ??? A JDialog can be owner less.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of how you really want your components to be laid out but the following snippet should achieve what I am guessing you are trying to do with your current code. Try to work as much as possible with LayoutManager's, Layout constraints, preferred/maximum/minimum sizes and avoid using setLocation/setSize/setBounds.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test5 {

    protected static void initUI() {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 0, 0));
        JTextField textfield = new JTextField(8);
        textfield.setBounds(10, 10, 40, 20);
        panel.add(textfield);
        dialog.add(panel);
        dialog.setSize(200, 100);
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

You should probably read about [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)'s. Take the time to go through it, understand how they work and the different ones that exists. You won't regret spending a few minutes on that.